# Data visualisation tool for Mac?

Tags: data-visualization

I am using JASP for quickly visualising and exploring some data. I like the speed and ease with which I can do this for quite a lot of data.

But I am looking for a tool that will give me more control over the visualisations and allow me to customise them. I have used python with different libraries in the past but it just takes too long with it.

Would appreciate any suggestions.